# audiolab for python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, scikits

I have python 2.7 installed in my system and I need to use the audiolab module.
I downloaded from the following site: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scikits.audiolab

When I import scikits.audiolab I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Python27/trystuff", line 1, in <module>

    from scikits.audiolab import formatinfo as format

     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scikits\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>

    __import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)

    ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 5):

There is a Windows binary build of scikits.audiolab (and a whole lot of other stuff) for python 2.7 here:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scikits.audiolab

audiolab will also require libsndfile.  The link is right there on that page, but I'll put it here too since libsndfile is great:
http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/#Download

PS: You will need to put the libsndfile-1.dll someplace python can find it.  If you don't mind wasting at tiny bit of disk space, you can drop a copy of it in the Python27\Lib\site-packages\scikits\audiolab\pysndfile directory.

Comment: which libsndfile? 64-bit or 32-bit?

Comment: or use [link shell extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html) to link it

Answer (score 0):

You need [pkg_resources](http://packages.python.org/distribute/pkg_resources.html) module which is a part of [setup_tools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) or the newer fork [distribute](http://packages.python.org/distribute/). The site you linked also has Windows binaries for you to install. I'd recommend the distribute module. They also provide you easy install/uninstall capabilities for third-party modules.